# xslt how to get not keyed nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Input xml:

```
    <Produkt><Index>275938</Index><Nazwa><RĘKAWICE BRAMKARSKIE PUMA 040959 01 SIZE.11></Nazwa><Ean>887119275938</Ean></Produkt>
    <Produkt><Index>275921</Index><Nazwa><RĘKAWICE BRAMKARSKIE PUMA 040959 01 SIZE.10></Nazwa><Ean>887119275921</Ean></Produkt>
    <Produkt><Index>1001128</Index><Nazwa><ZESTAW DO NURKOWANIA VIZARI JUNIOR XS 32-34></Nazwa><Ean>5902431001128</Ean></Produkt>
    <Produkt><Index>1001111</Index><Nazwa><ZESTAW DO NURKOWANIA VIZARI JUNIOR XXS 30-32></Nazwa><Ean>5902431001111</Ean></Produkt>
    <Produkt><Index>7194A</Index><Nazwa><PUCHAR PLASTIKOWY SREBRNO - NIEBIESKI 7194A></Nazwa><Ean>2010000242261</Ean></Produkt>
    <Produkt><Index>7194B</Index><Nazwa><PUCHAR PLASTIKOWY SREBRNO - NIEBIESKI 7194B></Nazwa><Ean>2010000242278</Ean></Produkt>
```

Keys:

```
    <xsl:key name="ProductSize" match="Produkt" use="substring-before(Nazwa, 'SIZE.')" />
    <xsl:key name="ProductSize2" match="Produkt" use="substring-before(translate(Nazwa, '0123456789#', '##########'), '##-##')" />
    <xsl:key name="Restofproducts" match="Produkt" use="???????" />
```

Hello i'm grouping products based on sizes hidden in name of products, and i need key to store all products which are not in any of other keys.

Expected grouping:

```
<xsl:key name="ProductSize" match="Produkt" use="substring-before(Nazwa, 'SIZE.')" />
- <Produkt><Nazwa>RĘKAWICE BRAMKARSKIE PUMA 040959 01 SIZE.11</Nazwa></Produkt>
- <Produkt><Nazwa>RĘKAWICE BRAMKARSKIE PUMA 040959 01 SIZE.10</Nazwa></Produkt>
<xsl:key name="ProductSize2" match="Produkt" use="substring-before(translate(Nazwa, '0123456789#', '##########'), '##-##')" />
- <Produkt><Nazwa>ZESTAW DO NURKOWANIA VIZARI JUNIOR XS 32-34</Nazwa></Produkt>
- <Produkt><Nazwa>ZESTAW DO NURKOWANIA VIZARI JUNIOR XXS 30-32</Nazwa></Produkt>
<xsl:key name="Restofproducts" match="Produkt" use="???????" />
- <Produkt><Nazwa>PUCHAR PLASTIKOWY SREBRNO - NIEBIESKI 7194A</Nazwa></Produkt>
- <Produkt><Nazwa>PUCHAR PLASTIKOWY SREBRNO - NIEBIESKI 7194B</Nazwa></Produkt>
```

Any ideas how "Restofproducts" should looks like?

Comment: use
<xsl:key name="Restofproducts" match="Produkt" use="not(substring-before(concat(Nazwa, 'SIZE.'), 'SIZE.') or substring-before(translate(Nazwa, '0123456789#', '##########'), '##-##'))" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean. Given the definition

```
<xsl:key name="ProductSize" 
         match="Produkt" 
         use="substring-before(concat(Nazwa, 'SIZE.'), 'SIZE.')" />
```

this key includes all the `Produkt` nodes. So when you say "to store all products which are not in any of other keys", there are no such products.

If you want each key to index only a subset of the `Produkt` elements, you need to define that subset in the match pattern, for example

```
<xsl:key name="ProductSize" 
         match="Produkt[contains(Nazwa, 'SIZE.')]" 
         use="substring-before(Nazwa, 'SIZE.')" />
```

You can then match the otherwise-unmatched elements using a complementary predicate, for example `match="Produkt[not([contains(Nazwa, 'SIZE.')) and not(...)]"`

Comment: great, this part: "match="Produkt[contains(Nazwa, 'SIZE.')]" solving my problem. Thanks!